# Pytest run entire test suite with a selectable set-up fixture

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I'd like to essentially "inherit" a pytest suite to test different implementations of a library using the same set of test functions. I'm struggling to find answers in Google and Stack Overflow, but I think a large part of my problem is that I don't know the correct pytest nomenclature for what I want.

I'm working on a library which contains multiple implementations of an interface. Let's call them `A` and `B`.

I've got a reasonably large test suite developed against implementation `A` and now I want to also run the same suite against `B` avoiding code duplication.

I've got a fixture for each implementation that spins up the necessary resources for a test instance of `A` and `B`.

```py
@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
def get_an_A():
    yield A(..)
```

And a fixture for B that depends on some other 3rd party fixtures.

```py
@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
def get_a_B(some_other_fixture):
    yield B(..)
```

And a test suite that's happy to run against_either

```py
def test_add_values_should_be_correct(my_A_or_B):
    assert my_A_or_B.of(1) + my_A_or_B.of(2) == my_A_or_B.of(3)
```

What I'd like to do is construct that `my_A_or_B` fixture that can provide `A`s using the `A` fixture in one context and `B`s using the `B` fixture in another context.

Ideally I'd like to be able to run something like this:

Run test suite against `A`:

```sh
> pytest tests/A
```

Run test suite against `B`:

```sh
> pytest tests/B
```

Run test suite against `A` then `B`

```sh
> pytest tests/
```

Is there a way of laying out my test suite that will allow me to do this?

Comment: I'd rather parametrize `my_A_or_B` fixture with both `A` and `B` so `pytest tests` runs the whole test suite, and use filtering to select specific test subsets. E.g. `pytest -k 'A'` would run only tests with `A` in test name (including parametrization part) etc.

Comment: This is the path I've ended up going down. Thank you @hoefling

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way is have all the tests in the same folder and run this (on both file's names and method's names, names must start with `test_` prefix)

```
python -m unittest discover <PATH_TO_THE_FOLDER>
```

Comment: Notice the question is about `pytest` tests, not `unittest` ones. `python -m unittest` won't even recognize test functions and silently skip them.